# Align a text in Flutter to make a restaurant menu

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a menu for a reastaurant like this one : -

[image]

I'm using Flutter and this is my code:

```
 return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        ListTile(
          title: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: Text( text, style: style, )),
              const SizedBox( width: 15 ),
              Text( '\$ $price', style: style,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Divider( color: Colors.white.withOpacity( 0.5 ),),
      ],
    );
```

But this is the result that I'm getting : -

[image]

Please, any help will be welcome.
And thanks in advance.

Comment: You have taken a column. So you divider will add after your listTile. 
Here in this scenario use Row and then add three widgets inside a single row and then add this complete row inside a ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ramji, @Dhruvil Patel, I try your code and it work fine, but it was making an overflow when the text was long, so I made some changes in your example and I got what I was looking for.
Thanks a lot for you help.
Here is what I dit.

```
return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded( child: Text( text, style: style, maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, ) ),
              ],),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Text( 
                    '.' * 150, 
                    style: style, 
                    maxLines: 1, 
                    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,)),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 80,
                  child: Text( 
                    '\$ $price', 
                    style: style,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,)),
              ],
            ),
            
          // Divider( color: Colors.white.withOpacity( 0.5 ),),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The result that you want to achieve can be done just by using the row widget, you don't have to wrap it up with ListTile. I am writing the code snippet of Row widget for you. You can copy paste it and it will work. Additionally I see that you are generating it in the column widget. If you have a dynamic array then I suggest that you use ListView Divider instead. It will have a divider to add between your rows as well. You can find more about it on flutter official documentation.

```
 Row(
children:[
//You may add some padding to Text for better looking UI. 
   Text("Chicken Masala"),
   Expanded(child:Divider()),
   Text("180")
])
```

Just replace your column's children with this row and you will be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved your issue like this:

Output of your issue : -

[image]

```
body: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      ListTile(
        title: Row(
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Cheese Burger',
            ),
            Expanded(child: Text('.' * 100, maxLines: 1)),
            const Text(
              '\$ 10',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Row(
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Chicken Masala Soup',
            ),
            Expanded(child: Text('.' * 100, maxLines: 1)),
            const Text(
              '\$ 10',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).